# Reading Columns without headers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have some code that reads all the CSV files in a certain folder and concatenates them into one excel file. This code works as long as the CSV's have headers but I'm wondering if there is a way to alter my code if my CSV's didn't have any headers.

Here is what works:

```
path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\workspace\folder'          
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    df = df[~df['Ran'].isin(['Active'])]
  
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)
```

What this is doing is deleting any row in my CSV's with the word "Active" under the "Ran" column. But if I didn't have a "Ran" header for this column, is there another way to read this and do the same thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  Sometimes you might want to create fake data for the question - as long as it faithfully represents the actual data.. The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].  `df.head()` sometimes is sufficient for Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 df = df[~df['Ran'].isin(['Active'])]
```

Instead of selecting a column by name, select it by index. If the `'Ran'` column is the third column in the csv use...

```
 df = df[~df.iloc[:,2].isin(['Active'])]
```

---

If some of your files have headers and some don't then you probably should look at the first line of each file before you make a DataFrame with it.

```
for filename in all_files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        first = next(f).split(',')
        if first == ['my','list','of','headers']:
            header=0
            names=None
        else:
            header=None
            names=['my','list','of','headers']
        f.seek(0) 
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=header,names=names)

    df = df[~df['Ran'].isin(['Active'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly ...

If the header is missing, yet you know the data format, you can pass the desired column labels as a list, such as: `['id', 'thing1', 'ran', 'other_stuff']` into the `names` parameter of `read_csv`.

Per the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> `names` : array-like, optional
> List of column names to use. If the file contains a header row, then you should explicitly pass `header=0` to override the column names. Duplicates in this list are not allowed.